# Writing the array elements on a new line, in the HTML table cell while converting to PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I am converting an HTML table to a PDF using the Winnovative converter tool.
I have created an HTML table programmatically and assigned an array to a table cell like this:

```
td10.Text dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
```

The table cell displays the text in a paragraph format, without any line breaks. I would like to split it at the comma, and write the next content(after the comma) on the new line in the same cell. For example, a line break after each comma.

I tried the following;

```
string descri = dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
            char[] delimiter1 = new char[] { ',' };
            string[] array2 = descri.Split(delimiter1,
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string item in array2)
            {
                td10.Text += item.ToString() + "\n";
            }
```

While debugging (in text visualizer) this separates the string after the comma and writes on a new line but when I open the PDF it still writes like the paragraph.

Is there any way to achieve this. I would appreciate your suggestions and help. Thank you.

Comment: Side-note: `item.ToString()` is quite useless since `item` is already a string. You can use this one-liner instead of the loop and inspect the result in the debugger: `string lines = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,array2);`. If the result looks correct the problem must be somewhere in `Winnovative` which i don't know.

Comment: Thanks Timm!! Looks like it is an issue with third party tool..I appreciate your input.